# XSLT 1.0: remove parentheses

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

How can I remove the parentheses from this "name" sentence?

**- input**

```
Sensor magnético (SM-1)
```

**- transform**

```
<xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
<xsl:value-of select="translate(name, $uppercase, $lowercase )" />
```

**- output**

```
sensor magnético **(** sm-1 **) <----- remove this**
```

Comment: If you already know `translate` you should know that `translate(string, '()', '')` will delete any `(` or `)` from string.

Comment: Tks Martin, resolve my problem calling "translate" twice times "<xsl:value-of select="translate(translate(name, '()', '' ), $uppercase, $lowercase)"/>", your tip helped me a lot

Answer (score 2):

You could just change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(name, $uppercase, $lowercase )" />
```

to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(name, concat($uppercase, '()'), $lowercase )" />
```

---

Or, if this is the only use for it, change the `$uppercase` variable to:

```
<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ()'" />
```